# application stopped unexpectedly,please try again later

Tags: android

this is my code for World_Heritage activity,please help me guys.it has three buttons(next,previous,first) and a image view.if i click next button the image should change

public class World_Heritage extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener 
{

```
ImageView draw = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
int a=0;
Button butnnext;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.worldheritage);
    Button butnpre = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonprevious);
    butnpre.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button butnfir = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonfirst);
    butnfir.setOnClickListener(this);

    butnnext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);
    butnnext.setOnClickListener(this);


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.buttonfirst:
        draw.setImageResource(R.drawable.agra_fort);
        a=0;
        break;

    case R.id.buttonnext:
        if(a==0)
        {
        draw.setImageResource(R.drawable.ajantha_caves);
        a=1;
        }
        else if(a==1)
        {
            draw.setImageResource(R.drawable.bhimbetka);
            a=2;
        }
        else if(a==2)
        {
            draw.setImageResource(R.drawable.champaner);
            a=3;
        }
        else if(a==3)
        {
            draw.setImageResource(R.drawable.chttrabadhi);
            a=4;
        }
        else if(a==4)
        {
            draw.setImageResource(R.drawable.church);
            a=5;
        }
        else if(a==5)
        {
            draw.setImageResource(R.drawable.elephanta);
            a=6;
        }
        else if(a==6)
        {
            draw.setImageResource(R.drawable.ellora_caves);
            draw.setClickable(false);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.buttonprevious:
        a--;
        butnnext.performClick();
        break;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: as i told u in your prev question move findViewById inside onCreate  method after setContentView

Comment: Rather than post two incomplete questions, you should have clicked [edit] underneath your previous question to add this new information.  This way you would have one _complete_ question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
ImageView draw = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

to

```
ImageView draw;
```

and under

```
setContentView(R.layout.worldheritage);
```

put

```
draw = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

The reason for this is because your `Views` such as `Buttons`, `ImagViews`, etc... are contained in your `Layout`. Your `layout` doesn't exist until you inflate it using `setCOntentView()` or `inflater` hence your `Views` will be `null`

Also, from now on, when commenters ask you to post code/logcat/anything else, please edit your OP instead of creating a new post. Use the "edit" button below the post

Comment: now the button "next" and "first" is working but the button "previous" is not working

Comment: What do you mean "is not working"? Do you get erro/unexpected results/something else? Are you sure `R.id.buttonprevious` is declared in `R.layout.worldheritage` properly?

Comment: when i click next button the image changes,but when i click previous button the image view is not changing.

Comment: That I'm not sure about without debugging and seeing exactly what happens. You may not be able to call the `onClick()` from within itself. You haven't broken out of the `switch` yet